How to make a circle orbit another circle in JavaFX?
I am currently writing a program to let the user build an atom in javafx, and i decided to show the user the valence electrons in an atom. I also thought it would be nice to make them spin, but I am running into some issues.
This is what I tried:
boolean protonsAreUnder1 = false;
if(numberOfProtons < 1){
    protonsAreUnder1 = true; 
}
    
if (!protonsAreUnder1){   
//checks if # of protons > 0, or throws exception
    int atomicNumber = numberOfProtons + numberOfNeutrons;

    String[] elementInfo = getElementInfo(numberOfProtons);
    String symbol = elementInfo[0];
    String name = elementInfo[1];
    String valenceElectronsString = elementInfo[2];
    int valenceElectrons  = Integer.parseInt(valenceElectronsString);

    String atomicMassString = Integer.toString(atomicNumber);
    symbolNumberLabel.setText(name + "(" + symbol + ") - " + atomicMassString);

    //max radius for atom, based on the number of nucleons
    double maxRadius = Math.sqrt(atomicNumber) * 2.5;

    double valenceShellRadius = maxRadius + 20;  

    Circle valenceCircle = new Circle(150, 150, valenceShellRadius, Color.TRANSPARENT);
    valenceCircle.setStroke(Color.BLACK );
    valenceCircle.setStrokeWidth(2);
    pane.getChildren().add(valenceCircle);

    double angleBetweenElectrons = 2 * Math.PI / valenceElectrons;

    for(int v = 0; v < valenceElectrons; v++){
        double angle = v * angleBetweenElectrons;
        double x = 150 + valenceShellRadius * Math.cos(angle);
        double y = 150 + valenceShellRadius * Math.sin(angle);

        Circle electron = new Circle(x, y, 3, Color.YELLOW);
        electron.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        electron.setStrokeWidth(1);
        pane.getChildren().add(electron);
        
       //this is where i was thinking of putting the orbit code
       //but i think this only rotates the electron by itself, and not around the atom
       RotateTransition rotateTransition = new RotateTransition(Duration.seconds(1), electron);
       rotateTransition.setByAngle(360); // Rotate 360 degrees
       rotateTransition.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
       rotateTransition.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
       rotateTransition.play();
    }

But when I run it, the electrons are not moving. I think they are just spinning around themselves.
